# How to load UV texture from blender to opengl android java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures, blender

ehhhh

hello guys
Im tried load UV texture which i made in blender. In blender it's ok
Figure loading ok, materials loading ok. But problem with texture.. i dont know whats wrong cos im new in textures 3d .(always using only 2d quad for opengl .. i mean only 2d orientation)

here my obj file of simple cube

```
   # Blender v2.72 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
    # www.blender.org
    mtllib ncube.mtl
    o Cube
    v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
    v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
    v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
    vt 0.000100 0.250000
    vt 0.250000 0.250000
    vt 0.250000 0.499900
    vt 0.499900 0.499900
    vt 0.499900 0.250000
    vt 0.749800 0.250000
    vt 0.250000 0.750000
    vt 0.250000 0.999900
    vt 0.000100 0.999900
    vt 0.250000 0.000100
    vt 0.499900 0.000100
    vt 0.250000 0.749800
    vt 0.000100 0.499900
    vt 0.749800 0.499900
    vt 0.000100 0.750000
    vt 0.499900 0.749800
    usemtl Material
    s off
    f 2/1 3/2 4/3
    f 8/4 7/5 6/6
    f 1/7 5/8 6/9
    f 2/10 6/11 7/5
    f 7/5 8/4 4/3
    f 1/12 4/3 8/4
    f 1/13 2/1 4/3
    f 5/14 8/4 6/6
    f 2/15 1/7 6/9
    f 3/2 2/10 7/5
    f 3/2 7/5 4/3
    f 5/16 1/12 8/4
```

For opengl i made fix cos faces loading in wrong way so fix was  f=f-1 when i parsing . If not minus than i dont get correct cube.
If cube without textures than faces look : f 2 3 4; so after fix it's look right : f 1 2 3;

But when i export obj file with texture than faces coming with slash   1/13 2/1 4/3  i dont know for what need other faces. it's first

here my class for loading figure

```
public class TestUV {
    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    public FloatBuffer mColorBuffer;
    public FloatBuffer mColorBufferKs;
    public FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer  mIndexBuffer;
     private short indicesF[];
     private float vertices[];
    private float textureCoords[];
   private float matcolors[];
    private float matcolorsKs[];
     OBJLoader loader;
     public int tempo[];
     public float tempFloat[];

    public TestUV(Context context, String filename) {
            loader = new OBJLoader(context);
            loader.loadVertAndInd(filename);
            tempFloat=loader.indices;


            short indices[] = new short[tempFloat.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < tempFloat.length; i++) {
                        indices[i] = (short)tempFloat[i];
                }

            indicesF=indices;
            vertices=loader.vertices;

            matcolors=loader.materialsKd;
            matcolorsKs=loader.materialsKs;
            textureCoords=loader.Vtextures;
            String temp = ""+matcolors.length;
             String temp1 = ""+matcolorsKs.length;
            Log.e("","LENGTH OF MATCOmatcolors.length "+temp+"   KS = "+temp1);
            ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mVertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(matcolors.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mColorBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mColorBuffer.put(matcolors);
        mColorBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(matcolorsKs.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mColorBufferKs = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mColorBufferKs.put(matcolorsKs);
        mColorBufferKs.position(0);

            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length*4);
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mIndexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
            mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
            mIndexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }
    public float xPos=0;
    public float yPos=0;
    public float zPos=0;
    public void setX(float x){xPos=x;}
    public void setY(float y){yPos=y;}
    public void setXYZ(float  x,float y,float z)
    {
        xPos=x;
        yPos=y;
        zPos=z;
    }
// draw our object
    /** WORK WITH LIGHT **/
    //**********************************************************/
    //float[] pos = {0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f}; //2
    float lightX = 0;
    float lightY =0;
    float[] red={1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    float[] lightpos = {0,0,-1,1};
    float[] lightpos1 = {0,0,0,0};
    float[] lightdir ={-0.5f,-0.6f,-0.7f};
    float[] lightdir1 ={0.5f,0.6f,0.7f};
    public final static int SS_SUNLIGHT = GL10.GL_LIGHT0;
    public final static int SS_SUNLIGHT1 = GL10.GL_LIGHT1;
    public final static int SS_SUNLIGHT2 = GL10.GL_LIGHT2;
    public FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float p[]){
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(p.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer fb = vbb.asFloatBuffer();  // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        fb.put(p);    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        fb.position(0);
        return fb;
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl,float xR,float yR) {

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();


           gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

           gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorBuffer);

           gl.glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, zPos);
           gl.glRotatef(xR, 0, 1, 0);  //rotate around y-axis

           gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, mColorBufferKs);

           gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, mColorBufferKs);

         gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

           gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL10.GL_NEAREST);
           gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL10.GL_NEAREST);
           gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //enable texture
            //ENABLES
           gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
           gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
           gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);



           gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

           gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesF.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,mIndexBuffer);
        //ENABLE TEXTURE!!!!!
             gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        //DISABLES
             gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
           gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
          gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
   }



    private int[] textures = new int[1];
    //////=================================================================
    public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context,int count) {
        // loading texture
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                count);

        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Clean up
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

}
```

code very bad and not cleaning sorry for this.
texture [image]
and screenshot how it's look on device
[image]

Please help someone :( i dont know what to do
My parser work corrcet. Just cant understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the asker I assume, but for anyone stumbling across this problem. You say:

> But when i export obj file with texture than faces coming with slash
>   1/13 2/1 4/3 i dont know for what need other faces

The second values (after the slash) are the indices for your textures. They are in a different order than your vertex indices.

I don't see the implementation of the loadVertAndInd() but would guess this is where the problem is. You need to organise the order of your texture uv-coordinates to match the indices of your vertices. One way to do this is create a texture buffer the size of vertex buffer, sample from the textureCoords using your textureIndices and place them in the texture buffer using the vertexIndices.